# Integration by parts appears to prove the existence of integrals that have discontinuity.

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts, piecewise-continuity

Consider the following integral:

$$\int \lfloor x \rfloor dx$$

I know the integral reduces to:

$$x \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac {\lfloor x \rfloor ^2}2 - \frac {\lfloor x \rfloor}2$$

However, if we use integration by parts:

$$\int \lfloor x \rfloor dx = x\lfloor x \rfloor - \int x (\lfloor x \rfloor)' dx$$

Using simple algebra:

$$\int x (\lfloor x \rfloor)' dx = \frac {\lfloor x \rfloor ^2}2 + \frac {\lfloor x \rfloor}2$$

Yet, this is a contradiction. The indefinite integral is always continuous, yet the final expression is a piecewise constant function with infinite jump discontinuities. Does integration by parts only work for continuous functions or something? This is incredibly confusing.

Comment: Check your notes. There are some conditions on the integrands...

Comment: Depending on the context, absolute continuity of $f,g$ is the usual condition for $\int f' g = fg - \int f g'$ almost everywhere.

Comment: the usual approach for piecewise function is to integrate it on the subintervals and sum up.

Comment: It is the correct approach for any useful definition of an integral...

Comment: i haven't said it is the only one approach. Btw. splitting the integration domain is  essential to every integration theory...

Comment: Like to proof that the indefinite integral is absolutely continuous? The base for integral by parts... or how do you define Riemann integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your argument is, as stated in the comments, the continuity of $u$ and $v$ are necessary conditions for applying the integration by parts. Take a look at [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Product_of_two_functions):

> The theorem can be derived as follows. Suppose $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ are two continuously differentiable functions...

As a side-note, according to the fact that:
$$\int_a^b f(x)\delta(x-x_0)dx=\begin{cases}f(x_0)&a<x_0<b\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and knowing:
$$d(\lfloor x \rfloor)=(\lfloor x \rfloor)'dx=\delta(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)dx$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function, one can write:
$$\int x d\lfloor x \rfloor=\int x\delta(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)dx$$
Therefore
$$\int_a^b x\delta(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)dx=\sum_{a<\lfloor x\rfloor<b}\lfloor x \rfloor$$

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Well, that was unexpected `:)`